# How to fix Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report, working on 3 tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have 3 table in my base, student, subject and studentsubject. I can link to a spring boot application the first two and work with basic crud methods, the problem occurs when I try to provide my method in the repository interface and I get Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. I created an `@Entity` out of the first two classes
while the third one is connected like this

```java
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="studentpredmet",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="predmet_id", referencedColumnName = "predmet_id"))
Set<Predmet> predmetiKojeStudentSlusa;
```

Error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-21T21:17:44.242+01:00 ERROR 14276 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.NeZnamApplication.main(NeZnamApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Repository.StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(com.beClean.neZnam.neZnam.Entity.Predmet); No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:423) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:399) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:352) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:242) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:372) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Nothing works from repository interface except basic CRUD method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'predmet' found for type 'Student'
```

tells that in your repository class you've defined a method referencing non-existing property, as your method's suffix is `*ByPredmet`, but the property name is `predmetiKojeStudentSlusa`

```java
List<Strundent> StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(Predmet predmet);
```

To solve the problem you could either

1. use `@Query` annotation

````java
@Query("select s from Student s where :predmet in s.predmetiKojeStudentSlusa")
List<Strundent> StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmet(@Param("predmet") Predmet predmet);
2) rename `predmetiKojeStudentSlusa` -> `predmeti` and rewrite the method as
```java
List<Strundent> StudentRepository.findAllStudentsByPredmeti(Set<Predmet> predmeti);
````

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation for examples of method naming

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it led me to fixing the problem, and the link was useful too. Issue was I had a method findAllStudentsByPredmets and it should be findAllStudentsByPredmeti as you stated. Thank you!